# All GRPC calls failed with DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

Tags: android, grpc, grpc-java

I have an android app which calls a GRPC service. Sometimes for some clients the GRPC calls starts failing with DEADLINE_EXCEEDED. The request doesn't reach the server. It seems like a DNS resolution issue because the AWS calls also fails with the error unable to resolve host. After a while AWS issue is resolved but the GRPC continues to fail. The app has to be restarted for it to work. The internet connection is up throughout.  I suspect the ManagedChannel is corrupted somehow. Any one faced this issue before? Is there a way reset the ManagedChannel without having to restart the app or having to initialize it again?

I am using grpc version 1.39.0.
It looks similar to this issue but that bug is supposed to be fixed in 1.7 version.
https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/0t9n1-2GTms

Comment: Cross-linking https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/9072

Comment: Any updates here? I have the same exception, but not from my device. I'm using `Geocoder.getFromLocation` function and for some cases I see that issue, don't understand the exact cause of that.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with using `.getFromLocation` any update on how to fix this error?